# How to compare rows in 2 different tables: mySQL - what's different

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT pid,cid,product_id,thickness FROM products WHERE thickness <> "";
SELECT cid,level,thickness FROM catalog WHERE thickness <> "";
```

All pid are mapped to the cid. I'm only interested in level 2 mapping.

Goal, I want to know which products DO NOT have the same value in thickness in both catalog, products. Note, products are attached to a category via cid and all products are attached to level 2 categories.

Comment: What do you mean by `I'm only interested in level 2 mapping`?

Comment: @JW all products are attached to level 2 cid. Child/Sub Categories.

Comment: can yo give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: @JW i get this error: Unknown column 'a.thinkness' in 'where clause' - the operator of course is fine. Weird why its not working.

Comment: @JW - desired result would show me product_id 's that DO NOT have the same value in thickness that is there in it's respective parent category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.pid, a.product_ID
FROM    products a
        INNER JOIN catalog b
            ON  a.cid = b.cid AND
                b.level = 2
WHERE   a.thickness <> b.thickess
```

Comment: see my updated answer. fixed the typo error. it should be `a.thickness`.

Comment: that worked perfectly! How would I see the ones that DO have the same value?

Comment: `WHERE   a.thickness = b.thickess`